# How can i delete multiple nodes, for a polygon, with Quantum GIS?

Tags: qgis

I know how to select a single node and delete it.
I can also click-drag to select MULTIPLE nodes. But if i click delete, only one node (from the higlighted list) is removed.

Can I delete all the highlighted nodes?

### UPDATE:

[Here's a quick YouTube clip, showing how it's not working](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lbgmNXXJCzA). U can see that when I select 2 or 3 nodes, only ONE is deleted.

Comment: I just tried this in 1.7.4 an all selected nodes were removed when i hit delete. Which version and operating system are you using?

Comment: QGIS Version: 1.9.90-alpha

Comment: Added YouTube video reproducing the problem.

Comment: Please report this bug. It works in 1.7.4. I just recreated what you did in the video.

Comment: May be related to http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5327

Comment: It's not just you!  This is broken for me too, both on Windows XP and Windows 7.  The delete selected tool usually remains greyed out.  The issue shown in the bug report listed by underdark is a different but equally annoying 'feature'.

Comment: @SylvesterSneekly I think that bug report is the same one, actually...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That was a bug [#5657](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5657) that was fixed already in master.