# How do I delete a point (not on a polygon)?

Tags: qgis

I want to delete points that is not part of a polygon. I can add points using Capture Point, but I can't delete them. The following solution does not work for points:

1. Select your layer
2. Enabled Editing
3. Choose the Node Tool
4. Click a point on your polygon
5. Use Command-click & drag to select multiple points with the marquee tool. (might be shift-click on Windows)
6. Use Delete key to delete the selected points (Fn+Delete on MacBook Pro)

Comment: Compare "How can i delete multiple nodes, for a polygon ..." http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25255/how-can-i-delete-multiple-nodes-for-a-polygon-with-quantum-gis

Answer (score 4):

Step 4 and 6 is wrong.

You will need to use the normal select tool (select point, rectangle, etc), and the delete feature button.

*Note: 4 and 6 would normally work except for the bug that is currently in the node tool.  Will be fixed in 1.8 release*