# Deleting more than one node at once in QGIS

Tags: qgis, editing, nodes, remove

I would like to delete some nodes in my layer. I've got them about 50 or even more.

I found some solutions here:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lbgmNXXJCzA&ab_channel=JustinAdler
- [How can i delete multiple nodes, for a polygon, with Quantum GIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25255/how-can-i-delete-multiple-nodes-for-a-polygon-with-quantum-gis)

but they don't work.

Is there some option to make i.e. rectangular selection within the selected item and remove several nodes simultaneously when hitting the `Del` button on the keyboard?

I would like something like here: [Remove a node in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166406/remove-a-node-in-qgis) but for more nodes at once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can edit the layer, then select the `vertex tool`, then draw a box, then hit `delete`

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks! I simply have odes roughly at the border of another, adjacent polygon, that's why I couldn't manage with it. I had to move these nodes away from this border and then I saw an effect you shave shown me.